# ¿Cómo puedo probar el comportamiento de un Hilo en JUnit?

Tags: java

He investigado sobre esto pero no logro encontrar un ejemplo claro o algo que me describa su objetivo y el como funciona el crear un caso de prueba para un Thread.

Comment: Las pruebas unitarias sirven para evaluar y validar los métodos de las clases en isolación, es decir en su forma más simple. El uso de hilos no es parte de las pruebas unitarias, en su lugar lo que evaluarías sería que el método o métodos que usas dentro del `run` puedan trabajar según lo esperado (asumiendo que no es un hilo eterno dentro de algo como `while(true) { ... }`).

Comment: Te agradesco mucho @LuiggiMendoza , me has sacado de esta duda, si es posible o quisa conoscas un framework con el cual se pueda hacer esto, he oido que talvez  Mockito lo puede hacer pero no estoy seguro.

Comment: Mockito sirve para mockear instancias de clases/interfaces a fin de simular un ambiente integrado p.e. simular la conexión a la base de datos. Te recomendaría que selecciones [edit] y agregues más información sobre tu caso para brindar más ayuda. Por ejemplo, podrías agregar el código que necesitas probar (no todo el código en sí, un [mcve] es suficiente)

Comment: Para esto no cuento con un ejemplo, puesto que tengo este trabajo como investigación  de (¿Cómo puedo probar el comportamiento de un Hilo en JUnit?) conseguir un ejemplo y ver si era posible. pero con tu primer respueste me aclaraste esa duda. Gracias de nuevo **@LuiggiMendoza**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las pruebas unitarias sirven para evaluar y validar los métodos de las clases en isolación, es decir en su forma más simple. El uso de hilos no es parte de las pruebas unitarias, en su lugar lo que evaluarías sería que el método o métodos que usas dentro del `run` puedan trabajar según lo esperado (asumiendo que no es un hilo eterno dentro de algo como `while`).

Por ejemplo, si tienes código como sigue:

```
public class MiHilo extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        DataService service = new DataService();
        List<Data> listaDatos = service.getDatos();
        for (Data dato : listaDatos) {
            /*
                cálculos pesados puestos en el hilo
                que terminan registrándose en "Data dato"
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Este código no se puede poner a pruebas puesto que:

1. Las pruebas unitarias no deberían probar métodos `void` que no reciben argumentos (a menos que sepas el estado de tu data antes y después de llamar al método).
2. Hay muchas cosas que se hacen en ese método:

   - Crear una instancia de service (una asociación a una clase desde dentro de un método)
   - Obtener los datos de dicho service
   - Usar un ciclo for para procesar cada elemento
   - Colocar operaciones complejas dentro del método

La idea de usar pruebas (en general, no solo para pruebas unitarias) es que puedas tener un ambiente controlado donde puedas controlar y simular la entrada y salida de datos y luego puedas corroborar que ante un dato de entrada X tengas un dato de salida Y esperado. Como muestra el método anterior del hilo, esto no se puede hacer con el diseño actual.

Para hacer esta clase testeable por pruebas unitarias sería rediseñar su estilo a través de métodos. Cada método deberá ser testeable por sí mismo, lo que nos llevaría a facilitar su ejecución.

A modo de ejemplo, muestro dos formans de cómo rediseñar la clase indicada previamente. Cada diseño tiene sus ventajas/desventajas, no existen balas de plata en este campo, así que puedes elegir el que más te agrade o puedes usar un diseño distinto que se acomode más a tu escenario y necesidades.

Diseño 1:

```
//Se cambia la relación a la clase DataService 
//para que sea un campo y se pueda "inyectar" a través del constructor
//esto facilita que se le pueda enviar un mock como parámetro
//y los datos provistos puedan ser más controlados
public class MiHilo extends Thread {
    private DataService service;
    public MiHilo(DataService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        List<Data> listaDatos = service.getDatos();
        for (Data dato : listaDatos) {
            procesaData(dato);
        }
    }

    //Así mismo, creamos un método que permite evaluar
    //los cambios realizados a Data dato
    //para luego evaluar los cambios que sufrió la variable
    public void procesaData(Data dato) {
        /* cálculos pesados puestos en el hilo */
    }
}
```

Diseño 2:

```
//Se cambia la relación a la clase DataService 
//para que sea un campo y se pueda "inyectar" a través del constructor
//esto facilita que se le pueda enviar un mock como parámetro
//y los datos provistos puedan ser más controlados
public class MiHilo extends Thread {
    private DataService service;

    public MiHilo(DataService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        List<Data> listaDatos = service.getDatos();
        for (Data dato : listaDatos) {
            Data resultado = procesaData(dato);
            //hacer algo con resultado aquí
            //por ejemplo, guardar
            service.guardar(resultado);
        }
    }

    //Así mismo, creamos un método que permite evaluar
    //los cambios realizados a Data dato.
    //A diferencia del caso anterior, lo que hacemos es
    //retornar una nueva instancia de Data.
    //Esto permite evaluar mejor la información particular
    //que ha sido modificada respecto a la información original
    public Data procesaData(Data dato) {
        Data resultado;
        /* cálculos pesados puestos en el hilo */
    }
}
```

Con estos diseños, las pruebas unitarias ya no se concentran en el método `run`, sino en el método `procesaData`. Así mismo, se puede mockear la instancia de `DataService` mediante alguna librería como [mockito](/questions/tagged/mockito) para simular los datos que deben ser devueltos mediante `DataService#getDatos` y `DataService#guardar`. La ventaja del segundo diseño sobre el primero es que el método `procesaData` es más sencillo de evaluar y puesto que provee un resultado (a diferencia del diseño 1 que es un `void`) se puede evaluar la salida, de modo que el método puede ser comprendido en el caso de prueba como una caja negra y además no modifica el estado de la información de entrada.

Tu prueba unitaria luciría así:

```
public class MiHiloTest {
    private MiHilo miHilo;

    @Before
    public void configuraTestCase() {
        DataService dataService = /* creación de mock */
        /* ... detalles del mock ... */
        miHilo = new MiHilo(dataService);
    }

    @Test
    public void procesaDataCaso1() {
        //Crear la instancia del parámetro
        //y completar el estado inicial
        Data dato = new Data();
        dato.setCampo1("val 1");
        dato.setCampo2("val 2");

        //aquí va la prueba unitaria
        Data resultado = miHilo.procesaData(dato);
        //y aquí las evaluaciones
        assertThat("val 1 modificado", equalTo(resultado.getCampo1());
        assertThat("val 2 modificado", equalTo(resultado.getCampo2());
        //resto de asserts para evaluar el resultado...
    }
}
```